# Using CKFinder with Amazon Cloudfront, not only S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, ckfinder, symfony-cmf

Out of the box, CKFinder is shipped with an adapter for S3 buckets which works nicely. Files are put into the bucket and fetched from it.

However, how can I, if at all, use Cloudfront in addition?

- Is it possible, or recommended, to choose a file and get its Cloudfront-URL instead of the S3 URL?
- Are Cloudfront URLs to be meant to last forever or are they rather volatile, i.e. are they only for the purpose of serving the files to user agents and hold for a few days, or can I *safely put cloudfront URLs to the long-term storage?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't safely put a *signed* URL for S3 or CloudFront into long-term storage for continuous use, if that's what you are asking, since the signature will be invalidated when (hopefully not "if") you rotate your keys.  Not sure if that's what you are thinking of, so you might want to clarify that.

Comment: I'm not sure how your Cloudfront URL-s looks like, but if they have a common prefix and contains a directory structure, then you can simply change `baseUrl` of CKFinder backend.